# MySQL Update Query using a left join

Tags: mysql, left-join

**Table Schema**

Table Name: `file_manager_folder`

Rows: `id` , `parentId`, `name`

My query simulates moving a folder into another folder and accepts an array using IN(?).

I want my update to only 'move' a folder if there is not already a folder with the same parentId and name. The kind of behaviour you would expect under any normal file system.

So for example:

```
UPDATE file_manager_folder set parentId = 54 where id IN( '1','2',3')
```

Would be a query which doesn't check anything about the parentId and name... But how can I get the left join to work.

Here is one I tried.. which totally doesn't work.

```
SELECT * FROM 
    file_manager_folders as a
LEFT JOIN file_manager_folders as b on a.id = b.id 
WHERE b.id IS NOT NULL and a.id IN("1","2","3") and a.parentId = 54
```

---

`UPDATE table1 LEFT JOIN table2 SET t1.x = t2.y ON condition WHERE conditions`

Answer (score 66, accepted):

So you want to move folders only if a folder of the same name under the target parent folder does *not* exist:

```
UPDATE file_manager_folder f1
LEFT OUTER JOIN file_manager_folder f2 
    ON f1.name = f2.name AND f2.parentId = 54
SET f1.parentId = 54 
WHERE f2.name IS NULL AND f1.id IN (1,2,3);
```

The join condition searches for a folder with the same name under the target parent.  The WHERE clause tests that no such folder exists (f2.name is null only if the outer join finds no match).

Comment: Thats perfect Bill. I can see I had the basics in place.. just incredibly off the mark! I don't know how you nailed it so quickly. I couldn't figure out what I wanted to join on.

Answer (score 2):

Kind of naive but how about this?

```
UPDATE file_manager_folder SET parentId = 54 
WHERE id IN( '1','2','3') 
AND parentId != 54 
AND name NOT IN (SELECT name FROM file_manager_folder WHERE id IN ('1', '2', '3'))
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this should be solved using a [unique constraint/index](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html) on the `parentid` and `name` columns.  Otherwise, anyone with INSERT/UPDATE access to the table can circumvent your business rule.

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX blah_uk ON FILE_MANAGER_FOLDER(parentId, name) USING BTREE
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use an **`NOT IN`** instead of **`LEFT join`** that degrade your performance.

Run Explain before you query and the problem is obvious.