# Update query with INNER Join

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables MANUAL_TRANSACTIONS and MANUAL_LIST_TEMP. What I wanted to achieve is to update the MANUAL_TRANSACTIONS with the information from MANUAL_LIST_TEMP. Here only records which is present in the MANUAL_LIST_TEMP table should be updated to MANUAL_TRANSACTIONS.

I have done something like below but the problem with following statement is it updates every records from MANUAL_TRANSACTIONS table.

```
UPDATE MANUAL_TRANSACTIONS 
SET ( "Age", "Assigned_To", "Attachments", "Comments", "Completed_Date_Time"
, "Content_Type", "Created", "Created_By","Cycle_Time (Crt to Complete)"
, "Cycle_Time (First reply)", "DISTRIBUTION_CHANNEL")=
        (SELECT MANUAL_LIST_TEMP."Age", MANUAL_LIST_TEMP."Assigned_To", 
        MANUAL_LIST_TEMP."Attachments", MANUAL_LIST_TEMP."Comments", 
        MANUAL_LIST_TEMP."Completed_Date_Time", MANUAL_LIST_TEMP."Content_Type",
        MANUAL_LIST_TEMP."Created", MANUAL_LIST_TEMP."Created_By", 
        MANUAL_LIST_TEMP."Cycle_Time (Crt to Complete)", 
        MANUAL_LIST_TEMP."Cycle_Time (First reply)", 
        MANUAL_LIST_TEMP."Distribution_Channel" 
        FROM MANUAL_LIST_TEMP 
        WHERE MANUAL_LIST_TEMP.ID = MANUAL_TRANSACTIONS.ID)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should also add the WHERE clause to your UPDATE statement:

```
UPDATE MANUAL_TRANSACTIONS 
SET ( "Age", "Assigned_To", "Attachments", "Comments", "Completed_Date_Time"
, "Content_Type", "Created", "Created_By","Cycle_Time (Crt to Complete)"
, "Cycle_Time (First reply)", "DISTRIBUTION_CHANNEL")=
        (SELECT MANUAL_LIST_TEMP."Age", MANUAL_LIST_TEMP."Assigned_To", 
        MANUAL_LIST_TEMP."Attachments", MANUAL_LIST_TEMP."Comments", 
        MANUAL_LIST_TEMP."Completed_Date_Time", MANUAL_LIST_TEMP."Content_Type",
        MANUAL_LIST_TEMP."Created", MANUAL_LIST_TEMP."Created_By", 
        MANUAL_LIST_TEMP."Cycle_Time (Crt to Complete)", 
        MANUAL_LIST_TEMP."Cycle_Time (First reply)", 
        MANUAL_LIST_TEMP."Distribution_Channel" 
        FROM MANUAL_LIST_TEMP 
        WHERE MANUAL_LIST_TEMP.ID = MANUAL_TRANSACTIONS.ID)
WHERE MANUAL_TRANSACTIONS.ID IN (SELECT MANUAL_LIST_TEMP.ID FROM MANUAL_LIST_TEMP);
```

For best results, convert your UPDATE into a MERGE statement:

```
MERGE INTO MANUAL_TRANSACTIONS tgt
USING (
        SELECT MANUAL_LIST_TEMP.ID,
        MANUAL_LIST_TEMP."Age", MANUAL_LIST_TEMP."Assigned_To", 
        MANUAL_LIST_TEMP."Attachments", MANUAL_LIST_TEMP."Comments", 
        MANUAL_LIST_TEMP."Completed_Date_Time", MANUAL_LIST_TEMP."Content_Type",
        MANUAL_LIST_TEMP."Created", MANUAL_LIST_TEMP."Created_By", 
        MANUAL_LIST_TEMP."Cycle_Time (Crt to Complete)", 
        MANUAL_LIST_TEMP."Cycle_Time (First reply)", 
        MANUAL_LIST_TEMP."Distribution_Channel" 
        FROM MANUAL_LIST_TEMP
) src
ON (tgt.ID = src.ID)
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE
SET tgt."Age" = src."Age"
  , tgt."Assigned_To" = src."Assigned_To"
  [...]
```

The MERGE statement will only update rows in `MANUAL_TRANSACTIONS` (the *target* table) which have matching rows in `MANUAL_LIST_TEMP` (the *source* table).

Comment: Thanks Danilo.. Could also tell me if i use Update statement instead of Merge, Does it cause any problem like performance issue?

Comment: A MERGE statement usually should perform better, especially for a very large number of records. The UPDATE should be just fine. As always, try both approaches and find out!

Answer (score 1):

You need one more where clause for UPDATE

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 UPDATE MANUAL_TRANSACTIONS 
    Set Age = MANUAL_LIST_TEMP.AGE, ....
    From MANUAL_TRANSACTIONS 
    inner join MANUAL_LIST_TEMP on MANUAL_LIST_TEMP.ID = MANUAL_TRANSACTIONS.ID
```

Comment: Will this even work? According to http://geekswithblogs.net/WillSmith/archive/2008/06/18/oracle-update-with-join-again.aspx and to http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_10008.htm#i2112182, it shouldn't.

Comment: you are correct but the question is posted with sql tag that's Y

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE MANUAL_TRANSACTIONS mt 
  left join MANUAL_LIST_TEMP mlt 
  on mt.ID = mlt.ID set mt.Age=mlt.Age .....
```

Comment: Will this even work? According to http://geekswithblogs.net/WillSmith/archive/2008/06/18/oracle-update-with-join-again.aspx and to http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_10008.htm#i2112182, it shouldn't.

Comment: yes, this will work you can check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3248531/mysql-update-query-using-a-left-join

Comment: The linked questions is about MySQL. This question is about Oracle.

Comment: yes Danilo you are correct, the question is posted with sql tag that y

Answer (score 0):

Please try this one:

```
UPDATE MANUAL_TRANSACTIONS mt INNER JOIN MANUAL_LIST_TEMP mlt 
on mt.ID = mlt.ID set mt.Age=mlt.Age,mt.Assigned_To=mlt.Assigned_To, .....;
```